# Makefile compile twice

Tags: makefile

I run make with this makefile on `main.cpp` which does nothing.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall

SRCDIR = .
TARGET = tfm

SRCS = $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

And, compile was done twice.

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -o tfm main.o
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And, compile was done twice.

No, it wasn't. The first line shows the compilation of `main.cpp` into `main.o` (which gets triggered by a built-in `make` rule for how to turn `*.cpp` into `*.o`).
The second shows the *link* step, linking `main.o` with libraries to result in the executable `tfm`.

In other words, everything is swimmingly beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Running make on the source code does not make much sense. You have to tell make what you want to generate. And you do not want to generate the source.

Complation is not done twice. The first line compiles the the second line links.